# How do I suppress echo of an SFTP get command in a bash script?

Tags: bash, cron, sftp

I have a bash script that logs into a remote server, pulls a file, then copies it on the local server to a subfolder. I want to run this as a scheduled cron job, so I don't want it printing any output. I managed to suppress the connection output by using the `-q` flag to the `sftp` command. But this script still prints:

```
sftp> get Export/data.xml
```

How do I go about suppressing this output? Below is my script.

```
sftp -q user@server.com <<EOF
get Export/data.xml
EOF
cp data.xml ./www/_resources/data
```

Answer (score 2):

Prefix the command with `@` as [`sftp` man](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp) says:

> Echo of the command may be suppressed by prefixing the command with a ‘@’ character.

```
@get Export/data.xml
```